# Jenkins auto build by Github webhook is not working

Tags: nginx, github, jenkins, docker

I have configured Jenkins for my project using Docker and GIT build setup also done. I am able to take a build. I would like to configure Webhook for auto build. once I check-in the code, Build has to auto trigger in Jenkins. I have done below mentioned steps. But, it is not working. Help me on how to setup webhook ( auto build ) in Jenkins and Git Hub repository.

Jenkins is running behind NGINX by reverse proxy. I am using latest Docker Jenkins image.

**Git Hub Configuration:**

> project repo -> settings -> webhooks - > add webhook  URL:
>   http://jenkinsusername:jenkinspassword@IP:port/jenkins/github-webhook/
>
> jenkins = webcontext of Jenkins
>
> Git Hub Recent Deliveries: success , response code : 200. But body is
>   empty.

**Response Header:**

> Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 0 Date: Mon, 05 Dec 2016
>   01:53:08 GMT Server: nginx/1.11.4 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

**Jenkins:**
project -> Build when a change is pushed to GitHub ( checked )

Guide me on how to setup auto build from GIT Hub to Jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve this issue by below steps.

> GIT Hub -> project repo -> settings -> Installed integrations ->Add
>   Service -> Jenkins (GitHub plugin)

Jenkins hook url : http://jenkinsusername:jenkinspassword@IP:port/jenkins/github-webhook/

Click Test Service and check Jenkins build

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pushing code through correct branch,this is one of the most common mistake

`git branch`

`Then Jenkins-> Job -> SCM -> Branches to build -> remove branch specifier and mention "**"`